# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined en javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

Me sale este error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined cabe decir que se esta utilizando dojo por parte front.

> dojo.js:14 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Object._getItemsFromLoadedData (/a/js/dojo1.6/dojo/./data/ItemFileReadStore.js:294)
>       at Object.fetchItemByIdentity (/a/js/dojo1.6/dojo/./data/ItemFileReadStore.js:481)
>       at Object._setValueAttr (/a/js/dojo1.6/dojo/../dijit/form/FilteringSelect.js:54)
>       at Object.set (/a/js/dojo1.6/dojo/../dijit/_WidgetBase.js:196)
>       at Object.setValue (/a/js/dojo1.6/dojo/../dijit/form/_FormWidget.js:103)
>       at Object.load (sancion.htm?action=cargarFrmAutoliquidaMultaManif&token=rO0ABXNyAC1wZS5nb2Iuc3Vu
>       at dojo.js:14
>       at _102 (dojo.js:14)
>       at _100 (dojo.js:14)
>       at dojo.Deferred.resolve.callback (dojo.js:14)

```
function listgetDatos(){        
    try{
        var codTipousuario = dijit.byId('selTipoUsuario').get('value'); //recibe el 01(OCE) o 02(Interviniente)
        var query = "action=cargarTipoUsuario&codTipousuario=" + codTipousuario ;
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sancion.htm",
            postData: query,
            handleAs: "json",
            sync: true,
            load: function(response) {
                var concepto = dijit.byId("selTipoOperador");
                var identifier = response.lista.cod_datacat;
                concepto.store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: response})
                concepto.setValue(identifier);
            }
        });
        return;
    } catch(e){
        console.warn("Error al cargar Conceptos por infractor : " + e);
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: En el código que muestras no se usa `length` en ninguna parte.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, parece que el error te da cuando invocas `ItemFileReadStore`, esto puede ocurrir si lo que viene en `response` no corresponde que lo que espera `ItemFileReadStore`.

Creo que deberías poner un `console.log`antes de invocar `ItemFileReadStore`y que mandes por consola lo que te llega a `response`.

Entiendo que dentro de `data`debería venir un array con nombre `items`según: [ItemFileReadStore](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html).